# No route to host, strange behavior

Tags: linux, routing, kvm-virtualization

On my Fedora35 host I'm running a KVM virtual machine with a bringed network.
When I try to connect to port 80 of the virtual machine from the host I'm getting `no route to host`, but all working fine for port 22

Please help me to understand why routing depends on the port number, which setting controls this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Disable the firewall on the VM and try again

Answer (score 1):

With *basic* installation and settings, this can only happen because there is a firewall on the VM. (there could be other causes, but not without customization that would be done by the administrator).

Disable the firewall and try again.

If you don't know how to disable the firewall, and the system on the VM is running Linux, have the command `iptables` available and do this until you figure out better:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Ok, it's a firewall thing, I forgot to reload firewall-cmd on the guest (rhel8.5) when openned port 80; what is still no clear to me why the host reported **no router to host**, not _connection timeout_ or _connection refused_; I wouldn't post this topic then

Comment: The "reject" clause in the firewall respond to the host with an ICMP error code "admin-prohibited" which sending programs return as error code of `EHOSTUNREACH` for. When its rejected as no port is listening, a TCP reset is returned instead which programs interpret as `ECONNREFUSED`. The ICMP option is arguably a better netizenship way of doing it as its protocol independent.